# Multiple Remote Desktop Sessions on Client Workstation

Tags: windows-server-2008, remote-desktop-services, rds

I have a Windows Server 2008 setup with a domain and 5 workstations connected to it.

I can have up to 10 people using remote desktop on the server at the same time.

However, I cannot get more than one remote desktop connection on the workstations, and I've changed the settings  on the workstations local policy to allow it but with no luck. All I need to know is, how can I allow multiple remote desktop sessions on the same workstation with the same user at the same time (as its possible on the server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, it's a breach of licensing.  there are various 'hacky' methods that you can find through Google, but it hardly comes under the heading of 'professional system administration'.

Comment: So i cant have 2 people remote in on the same username on 1 workstation? but there is settings for it :(

Comment: Which settings are you referring to?

Comment: Discussion here: http://blog.lan-tech.ca/2013/10/31/multiple-rdp-sessions-on-a-pc-legal-or-not/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot turn a desktop OS into a Terminal Server. Desktop operating system such as Windows 7 have one active session (be it local or via Remote Desktop) at any one time. As you're aware, servers are different.

Also, with Windows Server, be careful with your licencing. If you have 10 people logging into the TS, you need 10 user CALs and 10 user RDS CALs (one for each person who logs in). Just because the server lets you log in, doesn't mean it's properly licenced.

Comment: its properly licensed :)